# Babel Compile CSS files

Tags: reactjs, express, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm trying to configure a ReactJS application, using Express as back-end server. I'm facing an issue with .css files, when I run 'npm start' I'm getting this error.

```
/client/app.css Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| .layoutHeader {
|   background: #00AAFA;}
```

This is my application configuration.

**package.json**

```
 "scripts": {

    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=development node_modules/.bin/babel-node --presets 'react,es2015' server/server.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {


    "body-parser": "^1.17.1",
    "ejs": "^2.5.6",
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "mongoose": "^4.9.6",
    "react": "^15.5.4",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.30.10",
    "react-dom": "^15.5.4",
    "react-router": "^2.4.0",
    "react-router-redux": "^4.0.8",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "request": "^2.81.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {


    "babel-cli": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-core": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.11.0",
    "react-hot-loader": "^1.3.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.16.1",
    "webpack": "^2.4.1",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.10.2",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.18.0"
  }
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {

    devtool: "",
    entry: [
        'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
        path.join(path.resolve(__dirname), 'client', 'client.js')
    ],
    output: {
        path: path.join(path.resolve(__dirname), 'public', 'js'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/js/'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
        {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
            cacheDirectory: 'babel_cache',
          presets: debug ? ['es2015', 'react'] :  ['react', 'es2015']
        }
        }
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'style-loader!css-loader',
      }, {
        test: /\.css$/,
        include: /node_modules/,
        loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      }     
        ]
    },
}
```

And I didn't configure anything in .babelrc file.

I wanted to write individual CSS for every component and that can be imported to only that component.

I think I missed some configuration with babel, please help me to configure this application.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The webpack config looks correct.
Probably issue with import of CSS, it has to be smtl like that:

```
import './style.css'; where './' is path.
```

If you want to write CSS for every component, I suggest you take a look CSS Modules https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules

Comment: Hi Aksana Tolstoguzova, Thanks for the quick reply. Path to import the css is correct in the code.  I think this is the problem with babel loaders, because when I run the webpack individuall, it is able to bundle the code properly.

Comment: babel loader is used only for JS code, because it transpile ES6 to ES5 js. Did you install css-loaders and style-loaders? It has to be in package.json in devDependencies

Comment: Yes, I have them in my package.json file under devDependencies. I'm able to bundle the client-side code using webpack. When I run 'npm start' it is throwing the errors.

"start": 'NODE_ENV=development node_modules/.bin/babel-node --presets 'react,es2015' server/server.js'

Comment: Are you using webpack-dev-server in express? If so you need to ensure it is also pointed at the webpack config.

Comment: Yes, it's working fine if I remove CSS import. @Aksana Tolstoguzova

Comment: I'm not using webpack-dev-server  @Leon Aves

Comment: Remove the second block for CSS in webpack config, it does the same as the first and add comma before first CSS block

Answer (score 1):

If you are using webpack-dev-middleware you need to ensure you configure it with your webpack config:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

const webpackDevMiddleware = require('webpack-dev-middleware');

const webpackConfig = require('path/to/webpack.config.js');

const compiler = webpack(webpackConfig);

module.exports = webpackDevMiddleware(compiler, { /* options */ }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this is how I configured webpack in my server.js file.


import webpack from 'webpack';
import webpackConfig from '../webpack.config';
var compiler = webpack(webpackConfig);
app.use(require("webpack-dev-middleware") (compiler, {
  noInfo: true, publicPath: webpackConfig.output.publicPath
}));
app.use(require("webpack-hot-middleware")(compiler));